# How do I tell a file from directory in Python?

Tags: python, file, directory

When using os.listdir method I need to tell which item in the resulting list is a directory or just a file.

I've faced a problem when I had to go through all the directories in this list, and then add a  file in every single directory.

Is there a way to go through this list and remove all files from it? If it isn't possible to do with os.listdir, what method should I use instead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `os.path.isdir` to filter out the directories. Possibly something like

```
dirs = filter(os.path.isdir, os.listdir('/path'))
for dir in dirs:
    # add your file
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer! I checked help(os.path) and found out that maybe isfile(path) would be usefull too.

    isdir(s)
        Return true if the pathname refers to an existing directory.
    
    isfile(path)
        Test whether a path is a regular file

Comment: Don't forget the test for if a file is a soft link: islink, and ismount for if a file is the mountpoint for a device.

Comment: A heads up that `listdir()` doesn't return the files and directories of the given path (`'/path'` in the example) with absolute paths, but just the filename. And I think `isdir()`/`isfile()`etc checks relative to the current working directory, so the `filter()` might not work unless you turn the returned values of `listdir` into paths.

Answer (score 9):

This might be faster:

```
current, dirs, files = os.walk('/path').next()
```

The list of directories will be in the `dirs` variable.

Answer (score 4):

> dirs = filter(os.path.isdir, os.listdir('/path'))

Note this won't work unless '/path' is the current working directory. os.listdir() returns leafnames, so you'll be asking “os.path.isdir('file.txt')”, and if the current directory is elsewhere you'll be looking at the wrong 'file.txt'.

os.path.join() should be used on the output of os.listdir() to obtain a complete filename.

```
children= [os.path.join('/path', child) for child in os.listdir('/path')]
directories= filter(os.path.isdir, children)
```

Comment: I've done it this way.

    dir = os.listdir(dir)

    i=len(dir)-1
    while i>-1:
        if os.path.isfile(odir+'\\'+dir[i]):
            del dir[i]
        i = i-1

where dir is user defined directory. Works just fine.

Comment: Forgot to mention: odir = dir #'odir' stands for 'original directory'
So 'odir' contains user defined directory, after 'dir' is changed to a list. P.S. Is there any way to edit comments? O_o

Comment: You delete them and re-post, pretending nothing happened :-)

Comment: Anyhow... ‘odir+'\\'+dir[i]’ will work fine on Windows, but os.path.join() is the explicit, cross-platform way of doing it. Not that it probably matters for a script you're only going to use once...

Comment: It actually matters, because I myself use Linux from time to time and some friends, i just didn't think of right way to write it at first. I really should change it to os.path.join, thank you for mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

To evaluate your current directory children items:

```
import os

# Creates a list with all children items
cd_children = os.listdir()

# Iterate through the list
for item in cd_children:

    # If item is a directory (folder) do...
    if os.path.isdir(item):
        print('{:<13}{:<21}'.format('folder', item))

    # If item is a file do ...
    elif os.path.isfile(item):
        print('{:<13}{:<21}'.format('file', item))
```

Example **output**:

```
 folder          untitled folder      
 file            7972-orders.csv           
 file            8235-users.csv
 file            teads.py             
 file            table.csv
```

Used [os](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os-file-dir) and [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html).